# Manually drop table from MySQL database

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inserting query result to another table hangs on “Copying to temp table on disk” on MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/inserting-query-result-to-another-table-hangs-on-copying-to-temp-table-on-disk)

To look at the background my problem; I have run a query to import data to a new table from a query result in MySQL workbench (149.000.000 row would be decrease to 490.000 by grouping). But it is stopped unexpectedly because of connection timeout after 20000 seconds. In the table, there is no data when I look.

I executed the query "truncate table Concepts" to delete data inside also for executing the insertion query again later. I worked about an hour but not finished. So, I stopped the query and by using command line, executed "drop table Concepts" query to completely remove it.

It has been working for 3 hours but not finished. Is there any way to delete the table manually from database?

(Windows 7, 4gb ram, intel core2 duo 2.27GHz processor)

Comment: Is there a lock on the table or maybe an unfinished process running?

Comment: Only a primary key is set. I don't think there is a lock. The problem is non-finishing process. Drop table query is running from 3 hours and 30 minutes.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/06/16/slow-drop-table/

Comment: If you would log in on both sites with the same login method we could associate all your accounts together ...